# How to split the values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have to split the values using JavaScript and want to find the last occuring slash `/` from a string and replace the contents after the last slash `/` For example:

```
var word = "www.abc/def/ghf/ijk/**default.aspx**";
```

should become

```
var word ="www.abc/def/ghf/ijk/**replacement**";
```

The number of slashes may vary each time.

Comment: array = string.split("/"); array[array.length-1] = newString

Comment: There are `lastIndexOf`, `split`, `replace` in `String`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using regexp:

```
"www.abc/def/ghf/ijk/default.aspx".replace(/\/[^\/]+$/, "/replacement");
```

Comment: Gosh, I really need to revisit my regular expression skills.

Comment: Is it really necessary to use a regexp here? It's comparatively slower and less readable against the other answers...

Answer (score 5):

An alternative without regular expression (I just remembered `lastIndexOf()` method)

```
var word = "www.abc/def/ghf/ijk/default.aspx";
word = word.substring(0, word.lastIndexOf("/")) + "/replacement";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can array split on '/', then pop the last element off the array, and rejoin.

```
word = word.split('/');
word.pop();
word = word.join('/') + replacement;
```

Comment: Now if you can just add the `.push()` to mimic the replace, you'd be golden.

Answer (score 1):

What about using a combination of the `join()` and `split()` functions?

```
var word = "www.abc/def/ghf/ijk/default.aspx";

// split the word using a `/` as a delimiter
wordParts = word.split('/'); 

// replace the last element of the array
wordParts[wordParts.length-1] = 'replacement';

// join the array back to a string.
var finalWord = wordParts.join('/');
```

The number of slashes doesn't matter here because all that is done is to split the string at every instance of the delimiter (in this case a slash).

#### [Here is a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kZ7eq/)

Answer (score 1):

How about the KISS principle?

```
var word = "www.abc/def/ghf/ijk/default.aspx";
word = word.substring(0, word.lastIndexOf("/")) + "/replacement";
```

Comment: Adding 1 to lastIndexOf rather than a proceeding slash to the replacement string would be better, but still, upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Use regexp or arrays, something like:

```
[].splice.call(word = word.split('/'), -1, 1, 'replacement');
word = word.join('/');
```